# Dynamic subqueries

Tags: php, database

I have the following problem. I have the table `atr_product` that contains the columns `atr_id`, `product_id`.

Think that some registers are:

[image]

I send an `atr_id` array to my WS in PHP. For example I have `atr_ids = (1,2,3);`. So, when I receive these atr_ids, the query should return product_id 200.

If I send `atr_ids = (1)`, the Query should return product_id = (200,201) It is easy, but the atr_ids are dynamic, so I don't know how many ids the WS receive.

Comment: _It is easy_ so off you go and code it then

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: What is WS? Web Service? Web Server?

Comment: Btw for what you said first array should return 201 too...